# A mail client like Windows 10 Mail for all operating systems

Tags: windows, linux, osx, cross-platform, email-client

I like the layout of Windows 10 Mail - the built-in mail app.

[image]

I'm looking for a client organised in the same way - The accounts on the left, the mail in the middle and the reading pane on the right.

I like only seeing the folders for the account I've selected.

A dark mode is nice but non-essential.

I'd like this program to run on Windows, Mac and Ubuntu.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Nylas N1](https://nylas.com/) is the extensible, open source mail app.

It has a Dark Mode built in, a "Two Panel" layout and is extensible. It runs on Windows, OS X, Linux (`.deb` and `.rpm`) available.

The messages are shown tall in the middle panel - not just one line - when you shrink that section.

[image]

There is an [open feature request](https://github.com/nylas/N1/issues/1982) to only show the folders of the current mailbox, and a plugin would probably be possible to achieve this functionality.

Answer (score 2):

You could try [Thunderbird](https://www.mozilla.org/en-GB/thunderbird/) in the "Vertical View" Mode - I have mine set to a dark theme but there are lots available.

- Free, Gratis & Open Source
- Cross Platform OS-X, Windows & Linux
- Internationalisations for lots of locations
- Lots of other themes & extensions

[image: Thunderbird Screenshot]

Comment: Will look into it. I don't like seeing the folders for every account at once, but I have a feeling that is going to be the same for every client.

Comment: @Tim - You can collapse the accounts/folders that you are not currently using which helps.

Comment: Yes, that is a bonus. However, I have a lot of labels, and if I start to drag an email for a different account, it's pushed off the page. I have to remember to close each time I swirch

Comment: You can use right click move to which will even let you move to collapsed labels.